Silverstripe login with google, microsoft and apple ids
I am trying to give access to silverstripe cms with social login, but I am not  finding any way. How can I do that?
I am looking into structure of login in silverstripe but that didn't go well. I am expecting that someone will help me knowing and understanding how can I do that.

Do you have any specific question about this? As far as I see, SilverStripe does not provide such a functionality OOTB, but there are some modules

can you specify those modules?
